# Unity has jerky motion when using Vector2.Lerp

Tags: iphone, unity-game-engine

I made a 2D game with some sprite move to random position. I used **Vector2.Lerp** and **Time.deltaTime** to smooth transfer of sprite.
When I build this game in iOS ( I used iPhone 4s and iPhone 5 for test ) all sprite made jerky motion and cause my game lagging. But in Android game run very smoothly.
I used only 9 sprites and move all in same time. Can someone have any solution to fix this? Thanks.
P/s: Sorry about my bad English.

Comment: this needs more information...are you doing anything in the background? like loading images? or sounds? or playing sounds?

Comment: No. I just move some sprites ( exactly 9 sprites ) at same time in my scene. And don't do anything else.

Comment: have you tried looking at the profiler? are you seeing spikes in frame rate? if (as I suspect) garbage collection is your problem try to prevent using temporary lists and such. Reuse memory as much as possible. Also, it may be worth doing a **deep profile** and optimize your 4 most costly per update function calls.

Comment: I used **GameObject Pool** to reuse my sprites, but i think Vector2.Lerp cause that jerky motion, i will try to improve this method.

Comment: You should be using using vector2.lerp with Time.delraTime. If you are using that, the only thing i can think of is garbage collection spikes happenibg. But without any code there isnt much we can do.

Comment: `if (newPos != Vector2.zero)
    transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(transform.position,newPos,Time.deltaTime*2);` I only use this code, the **newPos** variable was assigned by another script.

Comment: hmmm, unless newPos is Vector2.zero a lot it should be ok. Have you looked at the profiler? And another thing: GameObject Pool? for 9 sprites? seriously? why? are you destroying and creating them a lot?

Comment: Yes. My game is all about destroying and creating those sprites. I dont use Unity Pro so i don't have the profiler :D :D

Comment: Ok sounds like you're being hit by garbage collection. How often do you create/destroy?

Comment: I create those sprites in start game ( that mean the **Instantiate Object** has place on **Start** function ). After that, i used GameObject Pool to reuse them and don't use any **Destroy** function. Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hard to divine the solution without more info, but some possibilities:

- Try doing your Lerp in `FixedUpdate` instead of `Update`.  Unity calls `FixedUpdate` at regular intervals, while `Update` is called basically as often as possible, thus `FixedUpdate` is lighter on your hardware.  `FixedUpdate` is also in-sync with Unity's physics, which will help avoid collision weirdness down the road.
- Not totally scientific, but elsewhere on StackOverflow I have seen this issue(iOS laggy `Lerps` specifically) solve by upping the frame rate cap from 30 to 60 fps.

Also, you probably don't want to use `Time.DeltaTime` for your `Lerp`.  `Lerp` takes(start position | end position | percentage between said positions), so while `transform.position` + `Time.DeltaTime` will result in an 'ease out' effect, it's not one you'll have a lot of control over.  I recommend [these](http://www.blueraja.com/blog/404/how-to-use-unity-3ds-linear-interpolation-vector3-lerp-correctly) [articles](http://chicounity3d.wordpress.com/2014/05/23/how-to-lerp-like-a-pro/) for a better understanding of `Lerp`, especially the second one because it demonstrates how to use `Lerp` to obtain all sorts of sexy smoothed movement.

Comment: Thanks for answers! I have tried to use **FixedUpdate** but nothing change. As you said, i used **Time.DeltaTime** for ease effect. But i don't know why in Android this **Lerp** work very smoothly, and in IOS always jerky ( I used Galaxy Note 1 for Android test ).

Comment: By the way. Can you answer my another question. Why the motion in Unity2D can't smoother than Unity3D?

Comment: Huh? Time.deltaTime is perfect for frame rate independent lerps? I use it all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Change the value of FPS using the following code

```
Application.targetFrameRate = 50;
```